# Null pointer exception in chaing callng

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
protected KeyStore intializeKeyStore(ServiceChannel serviceChannel) {
    try {
        PrivateKey privateKey = certificateHandler
                .parsePrivateKey(getPrivateKey(fromHttpsConfig)
                        .getDataHandler().getInputStream(),
                        getPrivateKey(fromHttpsConfig)
                                .getResourceAsPrivateKeyMetadata()
                                .getKeyPassword());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
    }
}
```

`getPrivateKey` this method is returning null how to handle null pointer exception efectivly please dont bother about other method in chaning calling of methods

Thanks in Advance please give me solution as soon as possible

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: Well, you're already catching the exception.  How do you *want* to handle it?  What should logically happen in your system when this exception is thrown?  Note that this code will *always* throw an exception, so you might just skip the whole thing and just do whatever it is you want the exception handler to do.

Comment: You might wanna change catch `Exception` to `NullPointerException` to avoid silently ignoring everything else.

Answer (score 2):

The most effective way of handling a null pointer exception is not to reference a null value.

That is, put the result of the call into a variable, check if it is null, and reference it (call methods, access fields, etc.) only if it is not null.

Instead of:

```
    PrivateKey privateKey =
        certificateHandler.parsePrivateKey(
            getPrivateKey(fromHttpsConfig).getDataHandler().getInputStream(),
            getPrivateKey(fromHttpsConfig)
            .getResourceAsPrivateKeyMetadata().getKeyPassword());
```

Do:

```
    EdgeResource resource = getPrivateKey(fromHttpsConfig);
    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    if ( resource != null ) {
        privateKey = certificateHandler.parsePrivateKey(
            resource.getDataHandler().getInputStream(),
            resource.getResourceAsPrivateKeyMetadata().getKeyPassword());
    }
```

Mind you, if `getDataHandler()` or `getResourceAsPrivateKeyMetadata()` could possible return null as well, you'll have to do the same for them before you call their methods.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice just for that first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ternary operator ?: will help you:

```
getPrivateKey(fromHttpsConfig) != null ?
    getPrivateKey(fromHttpsConfig).getDataHandler().getInputStream() :
    null
```